# about FCM registeration tokens

Tags: spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

It's my first time to using firebase cloud messaging.

The situation I am trying to develop is as follows.

Each user(=each app instance) is randomly grouped, and may not belong to a group, or may belong to multiple groups.(ex. client A belongs A,B,C group, client B belongs nothing, client C belongs A group)
And some groups can contain more than 100,000 app instances.

So rather than sending messages by registeration token, I'm trying to implement the group messaging feature through the topic subscription function.

what I'm curious about is that the Topic subscription feature and the individual transfer feature through tokens have been implemented with firebase admin sdk.
It seems that firebase admin sdk stores the token information by TCP(my-backend <-> google fcm).

The Firebase Admin SDK manages everything from token management to topic subscription feature, so I don't understand why people say we need to manage tokens individually in their own database.

front-end : react
back-end : spring boot

Answer (score 0):

*There are many reasons why one might want to implement their own token management with FCM, but discussing all of them is a bit beyond the scope of an answer on Stack Overflow.*

The main thing I'd recommend you to be aware of is that anyone can subscribe to any topic they know of. So if a user that is not part of a certain group learns/guesses the topic for that group, they can subscribe to that topic and get messages for that group.

This *may* or *may not* not be a problem for your use-case, that all depends. But if it **is** a problem, you should not use topics for delivering messages.